# recursive destructor for linked list

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list, destructor

I tried to search the topic but all the threads I found used while loops.
However I would like to do this recursively:

```
template <typename S>
struct node {
    S data;
    node<S> * next; 
};
```

this is the function I invoke in the destructor (pass the head as parameter) of the linked list:

```
void destroy(node<T> * n) {
    if(n->next != NULL){
        destroy(n->next);
    }
    delete n;
}
```

Unfortunately the result is a segmentation fault.
Can someone help me?

Edit: complete code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


template <typename T>
class List {
    private:

    template <typename S>
    struct node {
        S data;
        node<S> * next; 
    };

    node<T> * first;

    node<T> * get_last_p() {
        if(first != NULL){
            return get_last(first);
        }
        return NULL;
    }

    node<T> * get_last(node<T> * n) {
        if(n->next != NULL) {
            return get_last(n->next);
        } else {
            return n;
       }
       return NULL;
    }

    void destroy(node<T> * n) {
        if(n->next != NULL){
            destroy(n->next);
        }  
        delete n;
    }


    public:

    List() {first->next = 0;}
    ~List() {destroy(first);}

    void add(T element) {
        node<T> * new_element = new node<T>;
        new_element->data = element;
        if(first == NULL){
            first = new_element;
        } else {
            get_last_p()->next = new_element;
        }
    }

    T get_last() {
        return get_last_p()->data;
    }

    T get_first() {
        return first->data;
    }

};
```

Comment: Are you sure `n` is never null?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If you don't know where the problem is, you don't know where the problem isn't.  post your code.

Comment: i check if the pointer to the next element is null and if not I call the function with the next element, thats why I think that n can never be null.

Comment: @cmplx96 What about the first `n`?

Comment: @KABoissonneault why have a guessing game in the comments?  make the person post their code.

Comment: Are you sure that n->next is set to NULL for the last node? Can you please show us the code that uses this template?

Comment: Give us the minimum amount of code necessary to reproduce the error.

Comment: thanks for the answers, i just edited in the complete code

Comment: Length of list: if it's > sizeof(Stack) / sizeof(Frame), you'll get - oh, site name used correctly - stack overflow.

Comment: I tested it with 5 nodes

Comment: Right in the constructor's body: `List() {first->next = 0;}` -- `first` is uninitialized. Hello UB!

Comment: but the 'void add(T element)' function checks if 'first' is NULL and if so the added element is assigned to 'first'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see, in `List`'s constructor, `first` is not initialized, and is then immediately accessed. That is undefined behavior.
Even if `first` was somehow initialized to null in an unreliable way, and that `first->next = 0;` wouldn't crash somehow, you'd also fail in your destructor's `destroy`, since `destroy` assumes its original argument is not null.

I assume you meant to 
`List() : first{ new node{} } { first->next = nullptr; }`

If `first` is not meant to hold a value, then you're going to have to refactor your code to first initialize `first` to null - there's no working around that - and handle the case where `first` is null explicitely in all your code. You cannot assign `first->next` of a null, invalid or undefined pointer.

Comment: when I already initialize 'first' in the constructor, how can I check in my 'add' function if 'first' is holding a real value?

Comment: Edited to offer a solution that corresponds more closely to what you meant to do

Comment: it works with your constructor. i appreciate the help!